# Best practice for service links in XML?

Tags: xml, rest, jaxb, hyperlink, soa

#### Story

Developing enterprise applications you may have soon several RESTful services across your application. I am using JAXB for XML generation.
Embedding links in a XML response with a follow purpose to retrieve more information is a certain relief to human and consumers. The beauty of this approach links can point to resources that are provided by different services or applications.

#### Example

```
<order self='http://192.168.1.11:8080/customers/1234'>  
    <amount>23</amount>
    <product ref='http://192.168.1.11:8080/products/4554'/>  
    <customer ref='http://192.168.1.44:8080/customers/1234'/> 
</order>
```

#### Q

What is the best practice to embed such links of course with always the idea to have a low effort in terms of maintanance? Is there a sophisticated mechanism available?

Answer (score 0):

If your are using JAX-RS,  you can inject Atom links directly inside the entity objects you are sending to the client.

Here is [RESTEasy document](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/LinkHeader.html) and [jersey document](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/linking.html).

In my project, I'm using jersey, it's wonderful.